# Jsoup- getting certain attributes from website

Tags: java, jsoup

Recently I've started with Jsoup and ve found this sample code.Because I'm newb I can't figure out how does this find all links from website.Could anyone explain me what happens in for loop? Mostly, I've never used this syntax of for loop before, so it's little bit confusing for me.I don't certainly understand what loop contains.Thank you!

```
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Elements` implements `Iterable<Element>`

(`org.jsoup.select.Elements` and `java.lang.Iterable`)

So when you use the `for` syntax you loop over your `Elements` links, which is effectively a `List` of type `Element`.  The "Element link" is the local variable assigned to each element in 'links' as you iterate.

For further information, see:

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html
and
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 2):

As the names suggest, the classes `Elements` and `Element` are similar. One consist of a single element that has been selected, and the other one is a collection of multiple elements that are grouped together.

`Elements links` consists of `Element`-objects that have been selected.

The `Elements` class implements the following interfaces in java:

```
Cloneable, Iterable< Element>, Collection< Element>, List< Element>.
```

The `Elements` class is implemented using `ArrayList<Element>`, thus it is easy to add and remove `Element` objects from the `Elements` collection.

When it comes to the `for`-loop it is a simple way to iterate over each `Element` object in the `Elements` collection called links.

The loop will iterate through the collection, and assign the variable `link` to the current `Element` object in the collection called `links`. Inside the `for`-loop the content of the current `link` will be printed, and the loop starts over with the next `Element` object in the collection.

---

The syntax of this loop is often called a `for-each` loop, since it iterates over each object in a list or collection.

Read up on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)!

---

Look through the [Jsoup API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) docs to learn more about how to use it!

---

If you want to learn more about how Jsoup is implemented, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup)!